# Rails 4 & Controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I have three models - Project, Scope and Finalise.

The associations are:

Project has one scope
Scope belongs to project and has one finalise
Finalise belongs to Scope

Scope accepts nested attributes for Finalise.

Within Finalise, I have an attribute called :draft (boolean) and an attribute called :finalised_at (datetime)

I tried to write a function that would let me put a link on any project created with :draft saved as true. The link is meant to toggle :draft to false, which then displays a publication date (:finalised_at) on completed projects.

I am getting an error which is preventing me from creating a test project. The error is: undefined local variable or method `create_a_finalise' for - referring to the create action in my project controller. I think this has something to do with the create_a_finalise method being in my scope.rb model. I don't know how to fix this.

My finalise.rb has:

```
  after_validation :set_publish_time
  def set_publish_time
    self.finalised_at = Time.now  unless self.draft
  end
```

My scope.rb has:

```
after_create :create_a_finalise
  def create_a_finalise_dynamic(boolean)
    self.finalise.create draft: boolean
  end
```

My finalise_controller has:

```
def toggle_draft
    @finalise = Finalise.find(params[:finalise_id])
    @finalise.draft = false

    if @finalise.save
      redirect_to project_path(@finalise.scope.project), notice: 'Successfully Updated'
    else
      redirect_to project_path(@finalise.scope.project), alert: 'Not Updated'
    end
  end
```

The problematic part of my project_controller has:

```
def create
    #authorise @project
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    @project.creator_id = current_user.id
    @project.users << current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Can anyone see what I need to do to be able to create a new project. There is something wrong with the create action in my projects controller.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to `create_a_finalise`  but it is named `create_a_finalise_dynamic`.

```
after_create :create_a_finalise
  def create_a_finalise_dynamic
```

Change the name of the method to

```
  def create_a_finalise
```

and leave off the argument.

Comment: Hi Chloe, I tried this but it then has an error with the method: undefined local variable or method `boolean' for #<Scope:0x0000010dad0ee0>

Comment: Well you also have to remove the argument from `#create`! `self.finalise.create draft: boolean`. Set it to a hard coded value like `true`.

Comment: I don't have anything in my finalise controller create action for this. Not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Give the following a try-

```
# scope.rb

after_create :create_a_finalise
def create_a_finalise(val)
  self.create_finalise(draft: val)
end
```